# Existence of a reduced fiber implies generically reduced (Exercise III-74 from Geometry of Schemes)

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes

This question deals with a concrete exercise from [Geomerty of Schemes](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&opi=89978449&url=https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/papers/eisenbudharris.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjzsZi6rf-AAxVKxQIHHah3B6oQFnoECBUQAQ&usg=AOvVaw3usdrlkTi1DgXnq_xqASCS) by Eisenbud and Harris but also moreover the general philosophy attacking typical problems in algebraic geometry of following relative nature: say we have a "nice" enough map (having here sloppy said something "fibration like" in mind) $f:X \to Y$ of schemes over base field $K$, and assume $Y$ (wlog we can assume it to be affine) has some property $\mathcal{P}$ and say we have additional assumpion that there exist a fiber $X_y$ which has also property $\mathcal{P}$.

Natural question: in which situations one should "expect" that this property is carried/ "inherited" by neighbored fibers. Or even stronger, the property $\mathcal{P}$ inherited by $X$ *generically*? Let's consider the concrete problem from the book:

**Exercise III-74.** Let $K$ be a field, and let $ B =\mathbb{A}^{12}_K =\operatorname{Spec}K[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l]$. Consider the two conic curves $\mathcal{C}_i \subset \mathbb{P}^2_B$ given by

$$\mathcal{C}_1 :=V(aX^2+bY^2+cZ^2+dXY +eXZ+fYZ) \subset \ \\\\\ \operatorname{Proj} (K[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l][X,Y,Z]) =  \mathbb{P}^2_B $$

and similarly $\mathcal{C}_2 :=V(gX^2+hY^2+iZ^2+jXY +kXZ+lYZ) \subset \ \mathbb{P}^2_B $. Consider  $\mathcal{C}_1 \cap   \mathcal{C}_2 $.

**(a):** Show that the intersection $\mathcal{C}_1 \cap   \mathcal{C}_2 $ is *generically reduced* by showing that the canonical induced projection

$$ p_1:\mathcal{C}_1 \cap   \mathcal{C}_2 \subset \mathbb{P}^2_B \to B=\mathbb{A}^{12}_K $$

has a fiber consisting of four distinct (hence reduced and K-rational) points.

It's easy to see that there exist such fiber with respect this projection map $p_1$ which has this property. (consider the maximal ideal $(a-x_a, b-x_b,..., l-x_l) $ with $x_n \in K$ choosen general enough. Essentially that's Bezout's theorem.

So we can easily find such fibers, having obviously this property, expecially beeing reduced.

**Question:** But how can we conclude from this that $ \mathcal{C}_1 \cap   \mathcal{C}_2 $ is generically reduced, ie that there exist an open (wlog affine) subscheme $U =\operatorname{Spec} R \subset \mathcal{C}_1 \cap   \mathcal{C}_2 $ with reduced $R$.

**Metaquestion:** going back to the "motivation" at the beginning: Is there general "principle/ philosophy" behind such kind of argumentation techniques? For example, is there a "interesting" class of algebro geometric properties  $\mathcal{P}$ known, for which such argumentation technique as in presented exercise go through, ie $f:X \to Y$ "fibration-like", $Y$ and some fiber $X_y$ have property $\mathcal{P}$, then $X$ has it *generically* too?

Comment: I didn't think carefully about your example, but I might refer you to the following paper of Murayama for an overview of this and some some related questions.  Note, at least for reducedness, you want to work with geometric fibers.  Anyways, here are the references: https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.06737   and    
 https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/compositio-mathematica/article/uniform-treatment-of-grothendiecks-localization-problem/BFC0A54F5EDC2E10998B557D636017F4

Comment: These type of things are discussed in EGA IV_2 somewhere near Section 6.11 (where Nagata’s criterion is discussed).

Comment: Actually Grothendieck proves this after his discussion of eliminating Noetherian hypotheses (thus he does not need to prove it twice -- once with Noetherian hypothesis and once without).  It is in Section 9.8 of EGA IV_3.  Anyway, your exercise is much easier: just use the Jacobian criterion to prove that the critical locus of your morphism is a proper closed subset of $B$.

Comment: @JasonStarr: what I not completely got is where in this argument I exploit the observation that the canonical projection $p_1$ has a reduced fiber? Using Jacobian criterion we deduce that the smooth locus in $B$ with resp to $p_1$ is open. Then one knows that the preimage of it is regular. So if we can show that the smooth locus is not empty, we win. Note the base field $K$ was assumed to be arbitrary (see III.3.5 in the linked book). So it seems that this condition that there exist a reduced fiber, should somehow assure that the smooth locus cannot be empty. Do you see how to fill this gap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted by Jason Starr, the *Generic Principle* has been worked out in details by Grothendieck in EGA IV. If your French is not on top these days, the following version looks quite appealing (and can be found as Theorem 23.9 and 24.4 in Matsumura's *Commutative Ring Theory*) :

Let $f : X \longrightarrow Y$ be a **flat** (this is the expected fibration-like hypothesis), finite type morphism of Noetherian schemes with $X$ irreducible and let $y \in Y$.

$\bullet$ if $Y$ and $f^{-1}(y)$ satisfy the condition $R_k$, then there is a dense open subset $X' \subset X$ which satisfies the condition $R_k$.

$\bullet$ if $Y$ and $f^{-1}(y)$ satisfy the condition $S_k$, then there is a dense open subset $X' \subset X$ which satisfies the condition $S_k$.

Note that reduced is $R_0$ + $S_1$ (see for instane [Lemma 10.157.3 in *The Stack Project*](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/031R)), so that your expectation in the Metaquestion is correct.

**EDIT (added after the OP accepted the answer)** : As the OP was hoping for a proof that could be understood by a beginning graduate student, I provide two other proofs, which are probably more basic that the one based on the results in Matsumura's book I quoted above.

$\boxed{1} \ $ If $k$ is assmued to be perfect, one can prove a more general statement. Namely : *let $f : X \longrightarrow Y$ be a morphism between finite type $k$-schemes and let $y \in Y$ such that $Y$ is smooth at $y$. Assume that $\dim f^{-1}(y) = \dim X - \dim Y$ and that there exists $x \in f^{-1}(y)$ such that $f^{-1}(y)$ is smooth at $x$, then there exists an open neighborhood of $x \in X$ where $X$ is smooth.*

*Proof* : Consider the cotangent exact sequence:
$$f^{*} \Omega_{Y/k} \rightarrow \Omega_{X/k} \rightarrow \Omega_{X/Y} \rightarrow 0 $$
As the relative cotangent sheaf satisfies base change, we have:
$$\Omega_{X/Y} \otimes k(x) = \Omega_{f^{-1}(y)/k} \otimes k(x).$$
Hence, tensoring the above exact sequence by $k(x)$, we get:
$$ f^{*} \left(\Omega_{Y/k} \right) \otimes k(x) \rightarrow \Omega_{X/k} \otimes k(x) \rightarrow \Omega_{f^{-1}(y)/k} \otimes k(x) \rightarrow 0. $$
Since the fiber $f^{-1}(y)$ is smooth at $x$ and of dimension $\dim X - \dim Y$, we have $\dim_k \Omega_{f^{-1}(y)/k} \otimes k(x) = \dim X - \dim Y$. We also know that $Y$ is smooth at $y$, so that $\dim_k f^{*} \left(\Omega_{Y/k} \right) \otimes k(x) = \dim Y$. The above exact sequence then implies $\dim_k \Omega_{X/k} \otimes k(x) \leq \dim X$. Hence, $\dim \Omega_{X/k} \otimes k(x) = \dim X$. The field $k$ being perfect, there exists a non-empty open neighborhood $x \in U \subset X$ scuh that $\Omega_{X/k}$ is locally free on $U$ and then $X$ is smooth along $U$.

$\boxed{2} \ $ With no assumption on $k$, we can prove the following : *let $f : X \longrightarrow Y$ be a finite dominant morphism between finite type $k$-schemes. Assume that $Y$ is integral and that there is $y \in Y$ such that $f^{-1}(y)$ is scheme-theoretically equal to $q$ reduced points (say $x_1, \ldots, x_q$). Then, we can find an open neighborhood of say $x_1 \in U \subset X$ where $X$ is reduced.*

*Proof* :  The result being local on $X$ and $Y$, we can assume that both $X$ and $Y$ are affine. Let $A \longrightarrow B$ a finite monomorphism of finite-type $k$-algebras. We assume that $A$ is reduced and we let $\mathfrak{m}$ a maximal ideal of $A$ such that $B \otimes \mathfrak{m} =  k^{q}$. Let $f_1, \ldots, f_q$ be a basis of $B/\mathfrak{m}$ as a $k$ vector space and $e_1, \ldots, e_q$ elements in $B$ whose images in $B/ \mathfrak{m}$ equal the $f_i$. We also denote by $e_i$ the images of the $e_i$ in the local ring $B_{\mathfrak{m}}$. The $e_i$ induces a morphism of $A_{\mathfrak{m}}$-modules of finite type:
$$ \Phi : A_{\mathfrak{m}}^q \longrightarrow B_{\mathfrak{m}}.$$

Since the morphism induced by $\Phi$ betwen the corresponding quotient rings (by $\mathfrak{m}$) is an isomorphism, the Nakayama's lemma allows to conclude that $\Phi$ is an epimorphism. We also know that $A$ is a domain so that the $A_{\mathfrak{m}}$-module of finite type $A_{\mathfrak{m}}^q$ is torsion-free. We then easily check that $\operatorname{Ker}(\Phi)$ is a finite type $A_{\mathfrak{m}}$-module which satisfies :
$$\mathfrak{m}.\operatorname{Ker}(\Phi) = \operatorname{Ker}(\Phi).$$

The Nakayama's lemma implies $\operatorname{Ker}(\Phi) = \{0\}$ and $\Phi$ is a $K$-algebra isomorphism between $A_{\mathfrak{m}}^q$ and $B_{\mathfrak{m}}$. In particular, $B_{\mathfrak{m}}$ is reduced.

Let us finally check that there exists an open affine of $\operatorname{Spec}(B)$ which is equally reduced. Let:
$$\Psi : B \longrightarrow B_{\mathfrak{m}},$$
be the loalization morphism. Its kernel, an ideal of $B$, is finitely generated, say by $h_1, \ldots, h_q$. By definition, the $h_i$ are $0$ in $B_{\mathfrak{m}}$ if and only if we can find $s_i \in B \backslash \mathfrak{m}$ such that $s_i.h_i = 0 \in B$.Let then $s =s_1 \times \ldots \times s_q$. The ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ being prime, we have $s \in B \backslash \mathfrak{m}$, wo that $\Psi$ induces a morphism of local ring:
$$\Psi_s : R_{s} \rightarrow R_{\mathfrak{m}}.$$
The kernel of $\Psi_s$ is the image of the kernel of $\Psi$ in $R_s$ : this equal to $\{0\}$ by definition of $s$. The map $\Psi_s$ is then a monomorphims, so that $R_s$ is a subring of a reduced ring : it is a reduced ring!

Comment: essentially this completely solves the posted problem, but one detail still makes me ponder: in (a) one shows an even stonger statement about a fiber: it is not only a finite union of points with reduced scheme structure, but moreover every point is moreover $K$-rational. Also,  in the quoted book the authors not explicitly introduced this technical result you stated above. Do you maybe know an "elementary" way to conclude the generical reducedness directly, without exploiting this result? All in all this is an introductory book, and it's interesting to know if the claim can also

Comment: deduced with "elementary" tools, without exploitation of these Serre's $R_k, S_k$ characterizations. Do you have an  ad hoc idea?

Comment: I don't think the points being $K$-rational play such an important role. As Karl Schwede commented below your question, for this type of problem, you really want to deal with geometric fibers.

Comment: As for an elementary argument (which would somehow obscure the intuition you had in your metaquestion), this could go as follows. Let $b \in B$ such that the fiber of $p_1$ over $b$ is 4 reduced points say $x_i$. Then $\Omega_{X/B}$, module of relative differentials of $X$ over $B$, is locally free say at $x_1$. Thus there exists an open neighborhood of $x_1$ in $X$ such that the restriction of $\Omega_{X/B}$ to $U$ is locally free. Since the fiber of $p_1$ over $b$ is smooth of the correct dimension, we deduce that the cotangent map $\Omega_B \rightarrow \Omega_X$ is injective at $x_1$.

Comment: The module $\Omega_B$ being locally free, the cotangent exat sequence shows that $\Omega_X$ is locally free at $x_1$. We deduce that there exists an open neighborhood $V$ of $x_1$ in $X$ such that restriction of $\Omega_X$ to this open is locally free. And so $X$ is smooth at each points of $U$.

Comment: Yes, this also definitely works and also shows a much stronger statement about $X$ (smooth > regular > reduced). What I had in mind by (let me say very very) elemenary , was something like this: Say we have a regular local ring $(A, \mathfrak {m})$ ( obtained from $K[a,...,l]$ by localizing at a prime $ m$ , over which the fiber of $p_1$ is reduced & consists of 4 points ( ie whos existence one shows in the quoted exercise and which corresponds to your $ b$ from last comment).

Comment: Let now $\phi:A \to R$ be a *flat, finite* ring  map (in framework of the exercise $R$ can be easily constructed explicitly  by choosing a ring $S$ corresponding to some open affine $U \subset \mathcal{C}_1 \cap   \mathcal{C}_2 \subset \mathbb{P}^2_B$, which by construction is  a $K[a,...,l]$ algebra, and then set $R:= S \otimes_{K[a,...,l]} A$.

Comment: So the local version of the problem becomes, why this $R$ is reduced if we choose $U$ "small enough", under assumption that $R \otimes (A/ \mathfrak {m})=R/ \mathfrak {m} \cdot R $ is product of 4 copies of $K$ as assumed. And I' m wondering if it's possible to deduce directly that $R$ is reduced, by assuming there exist some   nilpotent $n \in R$ and concluding directly that it must be zero. What we immediately see that such $ n$ must be contained in the ideal $\mathfrak {m} \cdot R $. If we could somehow show that it must be in the image of $A$, since $A$ is reduced, and we win.

Comment: It looks all in all rather doable  just by a simple calculation - even without explicitly using notion of regularity, smoothness etc, so very basic - but I not see how to finish this part. Do you have an idea?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148220/discussion-between-libli-and-user267839).

Comment: There is still a detail in the added proof **(#2)** I not completely understand: Why holds the inclusion $\operatorname{Ker}(\Phi) \subset \mathfrak{m}.\operatorname{Ker}(\Phi) $? We know that $\operatorname{Ker}(\Phi)$ considered as $A_{\mathfrak{m}}$-module is finitely generated (since base ring Noetherian) and torsion free, but why this implies the quoted inclusion?

Comment: An update: the equality $\operatorname{Ker}(\Phi) = \mathfrak{m}.\operatorname{Ker}(\Phi)$  would surely hold if we in **(#2)** additionally assume that $B_{\mathfrak{m}}$ is flat over $A_{\mathfrak{m}}$ because of [tag/00HL](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00HL), but you not assumed it there, right? So I not see how else - without this additional flatness assumption - there the inclusion $\operatorname{Ker}(\Phi) \subset \mathfrak{m}.\operatorname{Ker}(\Phi)$ should follow. Could you sketch the idea?

Comment: @user267839 : You are right. Thanks for pointing out this! There is a gap in the proof (and probably in the statement). One needs to assume that the hypothesis holds for generic $y \in Y$. Then we can localize at a generic point on $Y$ where $f$ is flat.

Comment: But even if we add this flatness assumption in **(#2)** (indeed, in that case we get that $B_m \cong A_m^q$ as $A$- modules (!, that's the crucial problem) for free. But how we can then deduce from this that $B_m$ is reduced? Note, the $A$-mod iso $B_m \cong A_m^q$ not "sees" the ring structure of $B$, which carries the information about reducedness. Do you see how to remedy this problem in this "elementary" approach in **(#2)** under additional assumption $f$ to be flat?