# Finite monomorphism $A \to B$ with reduced $A$ and special fiber implies $B$ reduced

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, local-rings

I have a question about correctness of following statement claimed [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/453652) in $\boxed{2} \ $:

> Let $k$ arbitrary field, let $f : X \longrightarrow Y$ be a finite dominant morphism between finite type $k$-schemes. Assume that $Y$ is integral and that there is $y \in Y$ such that $f^{-1}(y)$ is scheme-theoretically equal to $q$ reduced points (say $x_1, \ldots, x_q$). Then, we can find an open neighborhood of say $x_1 \in U \subset X$ where $X$ is reduced.

It suffice to consider the **local version** given by a finite monomorphism  $A \longrightarrow B$ of finite-type $k$-algebras with $A=A_{\mathfrak{m}}$ local integral domain ( esp'ly reduced) with unique max ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ corresponding to $y$, and $B=B_{\mathfrak{m}}$ ( ie $B$ localized with respect $\mathfrak{m}$) and  $B/ (\mathfrak{m} \cdot B)=B\otimes_A A/ \mathfrak{m}= B\otimes_A k(y)=k^q$ by assumption. The question becomes why is $B$ reduced?

So philosophically, which preferably most mild conditions should  the map $A\to B$ satisfy such that $B$ "inherits" reducedness from $A$?

It seems that the quoted proof contains a gap I not know how to repair. The strategy in the linked proof is to take basis generators $f_1, \ldots, f_q$  of $B/ (\mathfrak{m} \cdot B)=k^q$ as a $k$ vector space and $e_1, \ldots, e_q$ be some lifts in $B$ of the $f_i$'s.  The $e_i$ induce a morphism of $A$-modules of finite type:

$$ \Phi : A^q \longrightarrow B $$

Since $B$ is finite $A$-module and by Nakayama lemma, this map is surjective.
**(Maybe) Key problem:** But there is a potential gap: It is not clear to me why under the above assumptions the inclusion

$$\mathfrak{m}.\operatorname{Ker}(\Phi) \supset \operatorname{Ker}(\Phi).$$

should hold? Having this, again Nakayama tells us that that the kernel $\operatorname{Ker}(\Phi)$ is zero and we win. But why this inclusion above holds? If we eg would additionally assume that $B$ is flat over $A$, then it follows from [tag/00HL](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00HL) , but note that flatness wasn't assumed.

Even thought I haven't a conterexample, note that to show the claim above, it would be even sufficient to show an even weaker statement that the kernel $\operatorname{Ker}(\Phi)$ is a radical ideal, but I also not see why thats holds here, only that it is obviously contained in $(\mathfrak{m})^q$.

So finally **the questions** become
**(I)** if the local version of the statement is true **without any additional assumpions** (eg like flatness),

then ( if (I) has positive answer ) **(II)** if the given proof can be "repaired relativelly elementary" (eg deduce $\operatorname{Ker}(\Phi)$ is zero or radical), ie the "gap" isn't a gap at all

and **(III)** if (I) is wrong, are there preferably relative mild additional assumpions on $A \to B$ (milder than flatness, compare with comments on the potential gap in the given proof above) turning the statement in a true one, ie that $B$ inherits reducedness from $A$?

Comment: What about $A=k[x]$ and $B=k[x]\times \left(k[x]/(x^2)\right)$ where $A\to B$ maps $x$ to $(x,x)$? Some assumptions seem to be missing.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn: You mean that fibers over max ideals of type $(x-a), a \neq 0$ are not reduced, but in contrast over $(x) \subset k[x]$ it is reduced if I'm not missing something, right? Concretely, $B \otimes A/(x)=B/B \cdot (x,x) $ and $(x,0),(0,x) \in B \cdot (x,x)$, so  $B \otimes A/(x)=k \times k$ reduced. And then these $A$ and $B$ with fiber at $(x)$ would satisfy the assumptions above. It seems to be a correct counterexample, if I don't miss anything

Comment: Ah, I misread what the example was, sorry.

Comment: This is not true. Let $C$ be a non reduced closed subscheme of $Y$ and let $X:=C\coprod Y$. Let $f:X\to Y$ be the natural map ($=$ the coproduct of the given closed immersion and of the identity). Then the statement is violated for any $y\in Y$, which lies on $C$ and where the local ring of $C$ is not reduced. I think that flatness was forgotten in the assumptions.

Comment: @DamianRössler: I see, so it should be supposed to add flatness to the assumptions, ok let's do it. But then I'm still not persuaded by the argument that $B$ is reduced, because then althought now we indeed can fill the gap I mentioned about and obtain $A^d \cong B $ as $A$-modules (!), (by the way: by flatness assumption we obtain this locally freeness even for free). But from this we not obtain anything about ring structure of $B$, so it seemingly not really helps to deduce reducedness of $B$, or not?

Comment: Note that the assumptions imply that the sheaf of differentials of $f$ vanishes in a neighbourhood of the fibre over $y$ (apply Nakayama and the fact that differentials are invariant under base change). Thus, if $f$ is flat, the morphism $f$ is étale in a neighbourhood of the fibre. But then $X$ is reduced in that neighbourhood (see https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/download/etale.pdf#page21 ).